# Sliding Up divs in jquery

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors, slideup

I have following divs

```
<div class="OffersContainer">
    <div class='special'>A</div>
    <div class='notspecial'>B</div>
    <div class='notspecial'>C</div>
    <div class='notspecial'>D</div>
    <div class='notspecial'>E</div>
    <div class='notspecial'>E</div>
    <span>Show more</span>
</div>
```

And on click of span, I want to slide Up so that only the first 3 divs having class 'notspecial' are visible.
I tried the following code but it slides up in wrong order

```
$(offers).filter("div.notspecial:lt(4)").slideUp();
```

Comment: `offers` is a variable containing all these divs. And `notspecialoffer` was a typo. Edited!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
$(".OffersContainer > span").on("click", function(){
  $(".special, .notspecial:gt(2)").slideUp();
});//
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="OffersContainer">
    <div class='special'>A</div>
    <div class='notspecial'>B</div>
    <div class='notspecial'>C</div>
    <div class='notspecial'>D</div>
    <div class='notspecial'>E</div>
    <div class='notspecial'>E</div>
    <span>Show more</span>
</div>
```